# WIX- Reinstalling MSI - not registring the component

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an MSI using WIX. This is working fine for install/Un-install.

When i tried to re-install the MSI it shows lot of errors. from the log it shows that could not register component.

```
ComponentRegister(ComponentId={A35FD4BC-66CA-4BE0-BCBA-EDEA2DFC7FD3},KeyPath=C:\Program Files\Common Files\{Appname}\Config\0.reg,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:56:53:819]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Components\CB4DF53AAC660EB4CBABDEAED2CFF73D 3: 1450

MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:56:53:835]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error

MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:56:53:835]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2908 

DEBUG: Error 2908:  Could not register component {A35FD4BC-66CA-4BE0-BCBA-EDEA2DFC7FD3}.

MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:57:16:602]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 

MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:57:16:617]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 

MSI (s) (54:F0) [13:57:16:633]: Product: -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908. The arguments are: {A35FD4BC-66CA-4BE0-BCBA-EDEA2DFC7FD3}, ,
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to deinstall it completely? check that the component is being removed at uninstall.
components with marked as permanent (componentattributes) will never be removed.
Neve be removed means they have a "shadowed" registration in the registry.

Comment: I have uninstalled completely, after uninstalling the key is deleting, but there is one key exists in HKLM/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/installer the key CB4DF53AAC660EB4CBABDEAED2CFF73D is present and the value is C:\Program Files\Common Files\{Appname}\Config\0.reg. how to delete the component from HKLM/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/installer

Comment: Component is not getting removed during uninstall. only the registrykey is removed. here is the code i am using        <Component Id="RegistryEntriesFrameWork" Directory="TARGETDIR" Guid ="25FDD9EA-A94F-41ef-B8DF-6E202D3687B6">  
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Stealth Framework" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="installed" Value="true" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>   how to delete the component during uninstall.

Comment: if you look in the msi, in the component table, wich attributes has this specific component?

Answer (score 0):

A Component registraton is identified by two things, Its PATH and Its registry entry. Looks like when you tried to reinstall, it is not matching with the KeyPath of where it was originally installed.
- Did you uninstall before trying to install?
- WHen you tried to install second time, did you pass the right installation location, as I see from the log the KeyPath, is containing {Appname}, seems like the install path was not passed during reinstall time.